# (Blazor / dotnet 6) when I deploy web app using azure, 500 error occurred

Tags: azure, blazor, devops, .net-6.0

When I deploy web app using azure, 500 error occurred.

[image]

I click the url in network of F12, displayed like this.
[image]

But I already set envirnment in client and server.

[image]

cf) category code
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is not a code problem. Because when I test in local, It works well.

Comment: But it doesn't work on Azure, so check your configurations. No useful information here.

Comment: Attached image of the code for api/category.

Comment: If your api is hosted on Azure, check on Application Insights the error for that controller